# java program to return the sum of all integers found in the parameter String

Tags: java

i want write a java program to return the sum of all integers found in the parameter String.
for example take a string like:" 12 hi when 8 and 9"
now the answer is 12+8+9=29.
but i really dont know even how to start can any one help in this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may start with replacing all non-numbers from the `string` with `space`, and `spilt` it based on the `space`

```
String str = "12 hi when 8 and 9";
str=str.replaceAll("[\\D]+"," ");
String[] numbers=str.split(" ");
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
    try{
        sum+=Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {
      //Just in case, the element in the array is not parse-able into Integer, Ignore it
    }
}
System.out.println("The sum is:"+sum);
```

Comment: how about the string "abc123def" . i expect the output to be 1+2+3 = 6. current prgm gives 123 as the output

Comment: @Coder17 that is a different requirement. output is 123 because for this code, `"123"` considered as **one** integer number

Answer (score 0):

You shall use Scanner to read your string

```
   Scanner s = new Scanner(your string);
```

And then read it using

```
  s.nextInt();
```

Then add these integers.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the general algorithm:**

1. Initialize your sum to zero.
2. Split the string by spaces, and for each token:

   - Try to convert the token into an integer.
   - If no exception is thrown, then add the integer to your sum.

---

**And here is a coding example:**

```
int sumString(String input)
{
    int output = 0;
    for (String token : input.split(" "))
    {
        try
        {
            output += Integer.parseInt(token);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int getSumOfIntegersInString(String string) {
    /*Split the String*/
    String[] stringArray = string.split(" ");
    int sum=0;
    int temp=0;
    for(int i=0;i<stringArray.length;i++){
        try{
            /*Convert the numbers in string to int*/
            temp = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
            sum += temp;
        }catch(Exception e){
            /*ignore*/
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
String s = " 12 hi when 8 and 9" ;
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
int start = 0;
int sum=0;
while(m.find(start)) {
    String n = m.group();
    sum += Integer.parseInt(n);
    start = m.end();
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

This approach does not require the items to be separated by spaces so it would work with "12hiwhen8and9".

Answer (score 0):

Assume your words are separated by whitespace(s)：

Then split your input string into "tokens"(continuous characters without whitespace).
And then loop them, try to convert each of them into integer, if exception thrown, means this token doesn't represents a integer.

Code:

```
public static int summary(String s) {
    String[] tokens = s.split("\\s+");
    int sum = 0;
    for(String token : tokens) {
        try {
            int val = Integer.parseInt(token);
            sum += val;
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ne){
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String s ="12 hi when 8 and 9";
     s=s.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");

     String[] numbersArray= s.split(" ");
     Integer sum = 0;
     for(int i = 0 ; i<numbersArray.length;i++){
         if(numbersArray[i].trim().length() != 0){
             Integer value = Integer.valueOf(numbersArray[i].trim());
             sum = sum + value;

         }
     }

     System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on the following code :-

```
public class Class02 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String str = "12 hi when 8 and 9";
        int sum = 0;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str.toLowerCase());
        while(st.hasMoreElements())
        {
            list.add(st.nextToken());
        }
        for(int i =0; i< list.size();i++)
        {
            char [] array = list.get(i).toCharArray();
            int num = array[0];
            if(!(num >= 'a' && num <= 'z'))
            {
                int number = Integer.valueOf((list.get(i).toString()));
                sum = sum + number;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this does not have the Java8 tag but I will put this out there in case someone finds it interesting

```
String str = "12 hi when 8 and 9";
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
      .filter(s -> s.matches("[0-9]+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum());
```

would nicely print out 29