# Program to find the sum of integers present in the input string

Tags: java, algorithm

input  = "12 text    1  abc12    c12lj 7 3  ";

output = 12 + 1 + 7 + 3 = 23

**Note** : In the input string the integers are separated by one or more spaces. Do not consider the alphanumeric sub string.

I have come across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551574/java-program-to-return-the-sum-of-all-integers-found-in-the-parameter-string). But I do no want my code to throw the NumberFormatException.

So far I have tried the below code and its working fine as expected for all the cases and not throwing any NumberFormatException

```
public class SumOfIntegersFromString {

private static final String NUMBER = "0123456789";

/** It matches one or many white spaces. **/
private static final String REG_EXPR_MATCH_ONE_OR_MORE_SPACES = "\\s+";

// Logic 1
private static int sumOfIntegersFromString(final String input) {
    int count = 0;
    String splits[] = input.split(REG_EXPR_MATCH_ONE_OR_MORE_SPACES);
    for (String s : splits) {
        if (isNumber(s.trim())) {
            Integer no = new Integer(s);
            count = count + no;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

private static boolean isNumber(String str) {
    boolean isNumber = Boolean.FALSE;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        String s = Character.toString(str.charAt(i));
        if (NUMBER.contains(s)) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    if (count == str.length()) {
        isNumber = Boolean.TRUE;
    }
    return isNumber;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "12 Test 3   7 text123   1 2 ";
    System.out.println(sumOfIntegersFromString(text));
}}
```

Any optimization in the above code or new logic which would be more optimized are welcome

Comment: Have you read the question completely? I am saying that there is similar question already mentioned here[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551574/java-program-to-return-the-sum-of-all-integers-found-in-the-parameter-string] which throws the excpetion

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: There is no issue in the code I wrote.I want the optimized solution for it

Comment: Why not use regular expression?

Comment: @Dummy Can you paste the logic here?

Comment: The code review stack exchange might be the place to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your `isNumber` method by regular expression matching:

```
private static final String REG_EXP_NUMBER = "\\d+";

private static boolean isNumber(String str) {
    return str.matches(REG_EXP_NUMBER);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a `Pattern` with a *regular expression* to detect digits surrounded by word boundaries. Then you might parse the numbers you find and add them to a `List<Integer>`. Assuming you're using Java 8+, you can map the values to `String` and collect with `Collectors.joining(" + ")` to generate your desired output (and get the actual sum by mapping to `int`). Like,

```
String text = "12 text 1 abc12 c12lj 7 3 ";
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\d+)\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    al.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
}
System.out.print(al.stream().map(x -> Integer.toString(x)) //
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" + ")));
System.out.print(" = ");
System.out.println(al.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
12 + 1 + 7 + 3 = 23
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a string and all words are separated by white space you can create a scanner object that will tokenize each sequence of characters between white spaces.  Then you can parse the string for an integer.  If it is not an integer the `try/catch` clause will do nothing.

```
import java.util.*;

public class AddNums {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = "hello 10 $xyz good 20 30 df";
  Scanner sequence = new Scanner(str);             
  int sum = 0;  
  while (sequence.hasNext()){
   String s = sequence.next();
     try {
      sum += Integer.parseInt(s);
     }
     catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
  }      
   System.out.println(sum);
 }   
}
```

Comment: Please read the question start to end before posting your answer